# Are the Observations in A Random Sample Independent?

Tags: sample

guys.

I am learning the t-test on my own.

The assumptions of t-test have been confusing to me.

The assumptions included "A random sample is used" and "The random sample is made up of independent observations", so I wondered the observations in a random sample may not be independent given the assumptions.

However, I really cannot figure out an example to illustrate my idea.

Could you please give me an example? Thanks.

Comment: A random sample means independent observations, its observations cannot be dependent, otherwise it's not a random sample.

Comment: [iid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables) assumptions

Comment: @JohnK It's possible that I misunderstand the intent of the original comment. I've removed our exchange.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the setting and the definition of "random sample", so it can be helpful to stress the independence assumption.

E.g. in a random sample drawn (without replacement) from a finite population, the observations are not independent.